# Gradle standalone plugin unknown property when loaded from github repository

Tags: github, gradle, plugins, properties

I've created a simple standalone Gradle plugin in Java and a Maven repository on GitHub for publishing the plugin. Everything works fine except retrieving project properties that should be available with the plugin. When I apply the plugin in another Gradle project, it can't find those properties.

It happens only when the plugin is loaded from the remote repository on GitHub. When loaded from a local repository, it works. Can the plugin implementation be somehow set to provide properties even from a remote repository? Or is this some GitHub feature that can't be hacked?

**Details follow:**

My `build.gradle` in the another project looks something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "GITHUB_REPO_URL"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "custom_plugin_group:custom_plugin:1.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: "custom_plugin"

task propertyTest {
    doLast {
        println project.customProperty
    }
}
```

When I try to run the the task *propertyTest*, it fails complaining that "Could not get unknown property 'customProperty' for root project 'another_project' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

I'm creating the property in the method *apply* in the main plugin class. I have tried following three approaches:

```java
// First approach - adding a simple value to extensions
public class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {            
        project.getExtensions().add("customProperty", "Custom property value");
    }
}
```

```java
// Second approach - setting extra property to extensions
public class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {            
        project.getExtensions().getExtraProperties().set("customProperty", "Custom property value");
    }
}
```

```java
// Third approach - adding a property instance to extensions
public class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {            
        Property<String> customProperty = project.getObjects().property(String.class);
        customProperty.set("Custom property value");
        project.getExtensions().add("customProperty ", customProperty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating extensions for your Gradle plugin you need create POJO class with fields:

```
class YourExtension {
  String customProperty
}
```

And then create extension in your plugin class:

```
public class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

  @Override
  public void apply(Project project) {
    project.getExtensions().create("extensionName", YourExtension.class);
  }
}
```

Now you can use extension in `build.gradle` file:

```
extensionName {
    customProperty = "value"
}
```